# Updating a highchart line using a button

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to update the red dashed line on this highchart plot using the text box and button below it.  I'm stuck on how to get it to work.  Right now I'm just trying to get the button press to move the line up slightly just so I can see if it's working.

http://jsfiddle.net/tZ8GM/

This is the function I'm trying to use to update it.

```
$("#setPtButton").click(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
    yAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            value : 68.1,
            color : 'red',
            dashStyle : 'longdash',
            width : 2
        }]
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a combination of [addPlotLine](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine) and [removePlotLine](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.removePlotLine).

```
$("#setPtButton").click(function() {
    var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
    chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('setline');     
    chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
            value: $('#setPoint').val(),
            color: 'red',
            width: 2,
            id: 'setline',
            dashStyle : 'longdash'
     });
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZ8GM/1/).

Comment: Awesome Thanks!  This has been bugging me forever.